# Using TypeScript to write Async Await tests in Jasmine and Protractor

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, protractor, karma-jasmine, typescript1.8

I'm writing Protractor (version 3) end-to-end tests using Jasmine (version 2) in TypeScript 1.8 so that I can use the `async await` feature of ES2016 (ES7).

However, when I run protractor using the transpiled JavaScript file I get an error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

The Jasmine test contains the following code:

```
let [a, b] = await Promise.all([returnsPromise1(), returnsPromise2()]);
```

which is transpiled (with no errors) into:

```
let [a, b] = yield Promise.all([returnsPromise1(), returnsPromise2()]);
```

and called within the `__awaiter` function. I'm targeting ES6 (ES2015) and running in Chrome.

Is the JavaScript being transpiled correctly or does Chrome not support this syntax? Or is this error being thrown by Protractor/Jasmine?

Comment: The test runs fine when I use `let a = await returnsPromise1(); let b = await returnsPromise2();`

Comment: suspect *destructuring + yield* is broken in chrome

Comment: @basarat thanks. I've reported an issue to Chrome to see if they know.